# Two Dimensional Array outputs one continuous row

Tags: c++, arrays

Hello I am new to C++ and am having trouble understanding why this two dimensional array is only producing one row and many columns. It reads the correct information but does not output it with the correct columns and rows.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <windows.h>

    using namespace std;

    char pat [9][9]= {'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$',
              '$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$',
              '$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$',
              '$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$',
              '$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$',
              '$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$',
              '$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$',
              '$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$',
              '$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'}; // 9x9 matrix
    int main ()
    {
int pattern,
    dimensions;


do
{
    cout << "1) Display Pattern 1" << endl;                //menu selections
    cout << "2) Display Pattern 2" << endl;
    cout << "3) Display Pattern 3" << endl;
    cout << "4) Display Pattern 4" << endl;
    cout << "5) Exit Program" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Please select an option. ";
    cin >> pattern;

    if (pattern == 1)
    {
        system("cls");
        do
        {
            cout << "Note: Choose a number between 1 and 10." << endl; 
            cout << "Choose a number ";
            cin >> dimensions;
            cout << endl;


            if (dimensions > 1 && dimensions < 10)
                           /* based on the user's input for dimension
                           it will output a square i.e. 2x2, 3x3, 4x4 etc */ 

            {
                cout << "True!" << endl;
                for (int rows = 0; rows < dimensions; rows++)
                {
                  for (int cols = 0;  cols < dimensions; cols++)
                    cout << pat[cols][rows];
                }

            }
            else 
            {
            cout << "Error! Number is not between this set!" << endl;
            Sleep(3000);
            cout << endl;
            }
        }
        while (pattern == 1);
    }
    else if (pattern == 2)
    {
    system("cls");
        do
        {
            cout << "Note: Choose a number between 1 and 10." << endl;
            cout << "Choose a number ";
            cin >> dimensions;
            cout << endl;


            if (dimensions > 1 && dimensions < 10)
            {
                cout << "True!";
            }
            else 
            {
            cout << "Error! Number is not between this set!" << endl;
            Sleep(3000);
            cout << endl;
            }
        }
        while (pattern == 2);
    }
    else if (pattern == 3)
    {
     system("cls");
        do
        {
            cout << "Note: Choose a number between 1 and 10." << endl;
            cout << "Choose a number ";
            cin >> dimensions;
            cout << endl;


            if (dimensions > 1 && dimensions < 10)
            {
                cout << "True!";
            }
            else 
            {
            cout << "Error! Number is not between this set!" << endl;
            Sleep(3000);
            cout << endl;
            }
        }
        while (pattern == 3);   
    }
    else if (pattern == 4)
    {
     system("cls");
        do
        {
            cout << "Note: Choose a number between 1 and 10." << endl;
            cout << "Choose a number ";
            cin >> dimensions;
            cout << endl;


            if (dimensions > 1 && dimensions < 10)
            {
                cout << "True!";
            }
            else 
            {
            cout << "Error! Number is not between this set!" << endl;
            Sleep(3000);
            cout << endl;
            }
        }
        while (pattern == 4);   
    }
    else if (pattern == 5)
    { 
    return 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Please input a valid entry." << endl << endl;
        Sleep(3000);
        cout << endl;
    }
}
while (pattern != 5);
```

}

Comment: Can you add some example input/output?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize a multidimensional array, you have to do it like so:

```
int multiarray[3][3] = 
{
{1,2,3},
{4,5,6},
{7,8,9}
};
```

Using nested braces to separate the dimensions.

After this to output it the way you want you do it as such:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    std::cout << multiarray[i][j];
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Nope, you don't have to. If the row's length is given explicitly, as in `char pat [9][9]`, then initializers are assigned sequentially to consecutive items: [0][0], [0][1], ...[0][8], [1][0], [1][1] and so on.

Answer (score 1):

When you're printing the array:

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < dimensions; rows++)
{
    for (int cols = 0;  cols < dimensions; cols++)
        cout << pat[cols][rows]
}
```

You never print a new line, so it's all on one row. You want something like this:

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < dimensions; rows++)
{
    for (int cols = 0;  cols < dimensions; cols++)
        cout << pat[cols][rows]
    cout << endl;
}
```